# Background image to div

Tags: css, html

For some reason the image in the background does not want to appear here is the code:

```
<style type='text/css'>

     .image-background {
        background: no-repeat center center;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        background-color: #cccccc !important;
        background-image:url('~/images/icons/button.png') !important;
        width: 420px  !important;
        height: 315px !important;
    }

</style>

<div id="example" class="image-background">

   some text...

</div>
```

The color appears and the text, but not the image. I triple check that is the correct path of the image since the only way I was able to make it appear was by using directly: `<img src="~/images/icons/button.png" />` What I really want to do is have one image as the background and in top of that another image, but I need to get this working

Answer (score 0):

Is your stylesheet in a separate folder if so you must use `../images` to navigate to it, this is a common occurrence.

Comment: The style format is on the same .cshtml file, above the code

Comment: I've tried the code and the image appears fine [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNmgpB)

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be at the url you entered...you should try the following depending on the folder the image or stylesheet is placed

```
 .image-background {
    background: no-repeat center center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color: #cccccc !important;
    background-image:url('../images/icons/button.png') !important;
    width: 420px  !important;
    height: 315px !important;
}
```

change `background-image:url('~/images/icons/button.png') !important;` to

```
background-image:url('../images/icons/button.png') !important;
```

or you can try a single period e.g

```
background-image:url('./images/icons/button.png') !important; /*may not work. the double period is sure*/
```

As you can see in my snippet, everything in your code looks fine except for the url. rather than (~) symbol try (..) or (.) symbol.

```css
     .image-background {
        background: no-repeat center center;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        background-color: #cccccc !important;
        background-image:url('http://animalspicwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Happy_Puppy_Wallpaper_ckrd.jpg') !important;
        width: 420px  !important;
        height: 315px !important;
    }
```

```html
<div id="example" class="image-background">

   some text...

</div>
```